# How to calculate the full load speed of a motor given the terminal voltage, armature resistance, armature current and torque?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, torque, angular-velocity

I'm currently working on an assignment question as shown:

**A 220V dc motor has an armature resistance of 0.5 Ω. The full load armature current is 20 A. The starting
torque of the motor is 880 N‐m, Find the full load speed of the motor.(Ans: 2052 r.p.m.)**

Here's what I've tried doing:

I calculated the Back E.M.F. using the formula **E.M.F. = Terminal voltage - Resistance * Current (220-0.5*20 = 210)**, I used the formula **Developed Torque * Angular velocity = E.M.F. * Current** (880*ω = 210*20). This gave me ω=4.77 rad/s which gives 45.6 rpm and is really far from the answer 2052 rpm. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The point is that the torque decreases with increase of rotational speed as back emf gets bigger.

Answer (score 1):

I think you confused starting torque with working torque. Your equation works with working torque. The starting torque happens when the motor is not moving yet, thus there is no EMF yet thus the starting current is 220/0.5=440A.

440A:880N-m=20A:40N-m. This equation works because of the structure of the motor does not change. Thus torque is proportional to the electromagnetic force, which is proportional to the current.

Thus you need to use 40N-m in your equation. Then you are OK.

Comment: When I use 40N-m, I get ω=105 rad/s but the answer in rad/s should be around 215 rad/s. (40*ω = 210*20)?

Comment: Then I do not know. Sorry

Comment: @Kira So do you know how to do now?

Comment: Yes, I was able to get the answer. Thank you

Comment: @Kira Good job.